# Adding a not equal to in a complicated mySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this large mySQL statement:

```
SELECT beer, style, brewery, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('38.613') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians('-77.25') ) + sin( radians('38.613') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM beerTable
GROUP BY bID
WHERE uID != '3'
HAVING distance < '50' ORDER BY distance
```

It finds all the beers with a given lat and long that are within 50 miles. I want it to take out duplicates, and entries where the user ID is equal to three.

I have gotten it to fill all my requirements except for filtering out ones where user id = 3. The above statement gives me an error. I have also tried with

```
uID <> 3
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` must come after the `WHERE`.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause needs to precede the `GROUP BY` clause. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Is uID a VARCHAR or an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` goes before the `group by`:

```
SELECT beer, style, brewery, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('38.613') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians('-77.25') ) + sin( radians('38.613') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM beerTable
WHERE uID <> 3
GROUP BY bID
HAVING distance < 50
ORDER BY distance ;
```

Also, don't put numeric constants in single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Damn, that makes total sense now. If it grouped first then it would not know if one of them was from user 3